# url-encode character with Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I work with WordBee API and it works fine on the browser and also with software if I don't use `filter` which is optional (see below API doc):

[http://api.wordbeetranslator.com:32570/projects?token={TOKENID}&filter={FILTER}](http://api.wordbeetranslator.com:32570/projects?token=%7BTOKENID%7D&filter=%7BFILTER%7D)

API doc example:

http://api.wordbee-translator.com:32570/projects?token=xxx&filter=ClientName='John'

The following is the GET Method I use, implemented with `filter`:

```
$resp = $project->request('GET', 'projects', [
        'query' => [
            'token' => $tokenId,
            'filter' => 'ClientName=John'
        ]
]);
```

When I send the request with Guzzle I get response '400 Bad Request', probably because of the `%3D` characters as appear below:

https://api.wordbee-translator.com:32570/projects?token=xxx&filter=ClientName%3DJohn

Note: I may need to url-encode the "=" character in ClientName=John

I found this but I'm not sure how/if to use it in my case:

> $request->getQuery()->setEncodingType(false);

How do I fix the request?